# Prove summation using induction

Tags: induction

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^3 = \left(\frac{n(n + 1)}{2}\right)^2$$

My basis step is $P(1)$ sets the $LHS = RHS = 1$.

For the inductive step, I assume $n = k$ holds for $k+1$.  On the $RHS$:

$$\left(\frac{(k + 1)((k + 1) + 1)}{2}\right)^2$$

But I don't know how to convert the summation into something that can evaluated algebraically.

Disclaimer: this is a question from an exam review sheet.

Comment: $\textbf{Hint:}$If the proposition holds for $k$, what gets added to both sides to get the proposition for $k+1$?

Comment: You need to start with a  base case ie j =1 then show its the same in sum and the formula

Comment: Is the index of the summation meant to be $j$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $P(n)$ means that the formula holds for $n$.

You assume that this holds for $n=k$ and you want to show that this holds for $n = k+1$.
On the right hand side you indeed have what you have written.

One the left hand side you have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i^3 = \left[\sum_{i=1}^{k} i^3\right] + (k+1)^3
$$
Now you can use the induction hypothesis and continue to get
$$
\left[\sum_{i=1}^{k} i^3\right] + (k+1)^3 = \left(\frac{k(n+1)}{2}\right)^2 + (k+1)^3.
$$
All that is left for you to show is that 
$$
\left(\frac{k(n+1)}{2}\right)^2 + (k+1)^3
$$
is equal to the right hand side that you have in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Base case: $n=1$,

$$\sum_{i=1}^1i^3=1^3=1=1^2=\left(\frac{2}{2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{1(1+1)}{2}\right)^2.$$

Induction: Suppose it holds for some $(n-1)\geq 1$. Then,

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^3=n^3+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i^3 =n^3+\left(\frac{(n-1)n}{2}\right)^2=n^3+\frac{n^4-2n^3+n^2}{4}$$

$$=\frac{n^4+2n^3+n^2}{4}=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2.$$

Note: I did the induction by showing that if the relationship holds for $n-1$ then it does as well for $n$ instead of the usual 'if it holds $n$ then it holds for $n+1$' purely out of convenience (to avoid expanding $(n+1)^3$). However, if you want, you can show that 'if it holds $n$ then it holds for $n+1$' pretty much in an identical fashion.